# How to find asymptotics of integrand?

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics

Let  $ f \in C ([0, \infty)) $ be s. t. $$f(x) \int_0^x f(t)^2 dt \to 1, x \to \infty.$$
How to prove that $f(x) \sim \left( \frac 1 {3x} \right)^{1/3} $ as $x \to \infty?$

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^n$, you'll find $n=\frac{-1}{3}$

Comment: @ metacompactness : So what?

Comment: so $f(x)\sim x^{\frac{-1}{3}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define
$$
F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
$$
For any $\epsilon\gt0$ there is an $M$, so that if $x\ge M$,
$$
1-\epsilon\le f(x)F(x)\le1+\epsilon\tag{2}
$$
Squaring yields
$$
(1-\epsilon)^2
\le F(x)^2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x)
\le(1+\epsilon)^2\tag{3}
$$
Thus,
$$
3(1-\epsilon)^2
\le\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x)^3
\le3(1+\epsilon)^2\tag{4}
$$
and so,
$$
\left(3(1-\epsilon)^2x+C\right)^{1/3}\le F(x)\le\left(3(1+\epsilon)^2x+C\right)^{1/3}\tag{5}
$$
and finally,
$$
\frac{1-\epsilon}{\left(3(1+\epsilon)^2x+C\right)^{1/3}}
\le f(x)
\le\frac{1+\epsilon}{\left(3(1-\epsilon)^2x+C\right)^{1/3}}\tag{6}
$$
Therefore, by the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem),
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)(3x)^{1/3}=1\tag{7}
$$

Comment: @ robjohn: Could you explain this place "and finally, ..." in detail? Can we differentiate inequalities?

Comment: @user64494: That is just an application of $(2)$.

Comment: @ robjohn: One more question. Is $$ F(x)^2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x)= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x)^3$$ true?

Comment: @user64494: other than a missing factor of $3$, yes.

Comment: @ robjohn: There is no any (2) in your answer.

Comment: @user64494: reload the page.